# Is it ok to have RelayCommand in View?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand, commandbinding

I have been in WPF for past few years but haven't done any of my projects from the scratch.  Now, I got a chance to do so.

I have started to put some base before moving into project.  I have created a separate WPF project for `view` and class library for `ViewModel`

I got struck in the beginning itself, I had a plan to have `RelayCommand` in `ViewModel` that work as interface to delegate the action from `View` to `Viewmodel`.

My question is, Am I right to have the `RelayCommand` in `ViewModel`?

I expected that it should be in `ViewModel` but the following code in `RelayCommand`

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

`CommandManager` required `PresentationCore` which is WPF specific assembly.  I dont want to add that in my `ViewModel`.

Do I need to have the `RelayCommand` in my `View`?

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely correct for putting the RelayCommand in your ViewModel. This makes it available for testing purposes etc.!

You should remove the code in `CanExecuteChanged` and expose a method on your `RelayCommand` implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Call this when the CanExecute of the command has changed, this allows things like UI to update.
/// </summary>
public void ExecuteChanged()
{
   CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke( this, EventArgs.Empty );
}
```

which you would then call (from somewhere else in your ViewModel) whenever the `CanExecute` boolean has changed on your command.

Of course, if you don't have a special method that determines whether or not your command can be executed, you'd call `ExecuteChanged()` from your `CanExecute` property setter.